# Why does not Eclipse debugger stop at break-point?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When I try to debug my code, I set a break-point inside a method which is called from another method. The debugger does not stop at that point. But if I set the break-point in the caller method (before my other method) the execution does stop there.

I can see in the Debug tab that there is a line that says:

"**$Proxy267.myMethod(String) line: not available**".

What I have tried:

- I have used "Step into" from the caller method (line "$Proxy267.myMethod(String) line: not available" appears at Debug tab).
- I have checked "Edit Source Lookup" (the package of the second method is there).
- I have tried "Run to this line" to stop at my failed break-point while the project execution was suspended in a previous method (execution does not stop).

How can I stop there?

---

My environment:

- Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
- Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
- JDK: jdk1.8.0_131
- Tomcat v9.0 Server

Comment: Which dependencies do you use? Is this happening with something like a bytecode generating library as [Mockito](http://mockito.org) for unit testing?

Comment: Both methods are in basic Java classes I have created, without using any dependency. JUnit and Mockito work fine in other parts of the project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging's step into won't work on own code: MyClass$Proxy$\_$$\_WeldClientProxy.myMethod() line: not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402283/debuggings-step-into-wont-work-on-own-code-myclassproxy-weldclientproxy)

Comment: I checked that question firstly and tried the possible solutions offered without any success.